# Why I can't release TTURLJSONResponse in UIViewController, but I can when I do it using TTURLRequestModel?

Tags: three20

Why I can't release TTURLJSONResponse in UIViewController, but I can when I do it using TTURLRequestModel?

When I use TTURLJSONResponse, it gives me EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Any idea why? is it gotta do with

```
[super requestDidFinishLoad:request];
```

Because in UIVIewController, it doesn't have that.

Cheers,
Mickey

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say w/o more code, but I'd say this isn't specific to Three20 or ViewController vs Model, but rather just the fact that you're trying to access something that you've de-alloced.

Have you tried using Three20's `TT_RELEASE_SAFELY()` method?

Or tracing your reference counting? (eg making sure you're retaining anything passed in to your class if you want to make sure it stays around)